# create a dictionary from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

my csv program is 
studentid,firstname,midterm,final,total,grade
20135447,Delta,47.00,37.00,65.00,DC
20144521,Jeffrey,36.00,22.00,27.60,FF

l tried this code

```
with open('marks.csv')as file:
line=csv.reader(file)
mydict={rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in line}
print(mydict)
```

l got the following traceback error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 3, in 
  File "", line 3, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

but my desired output is
{20135447:['Delta','47.00','37.00','65.00','DC'], '20144521':['Jeffrey','36.00','22.00','27.60','FF']}

please help me

Comment: You have a blank line at the end of your csv file.

Comment: @DonkeyKong thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
mydic = dict()
with open('marks.csv') as myfile:
    line = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in line:
        mydic[row[0]] = row[1:]
```